# Specify range of variable in a equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have a simple integral, I get the answer in terms of (h-1) whereas I know h is smaller than 1 and greater than zero. How could I implement this is the fully simplify.

```
FullSimplify[
  Integrate[t1^2*E^((1 - h)*s0*t1), {t1, 0, T}]
]
```

Answer (score 8):

Add Assumptions :

```
zw=FullSimplify[
  Integrate[t1^2*E^((1 - h)*s0*t1), {t1, 0, T}], 
  Assumptions -> 0 < h < 1
]
```

**Addendum**

```
zw /. h -> 1 - m /. m -> 1 - h
(*-((2 + E^((1 - h) s0 T) (-2 + (1 - h) s0 T (2 - (1 - h) s0 T)))/((1 - 
h)^3 s0^3))*)
```

shows the result with terms `1-h`

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question.  Mathematica gives the same answer with and without the assumption.

Comment: @ikado Thanks, I modified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would like to show the result in terms of `1-h` rather than `-(-1+h)`.  To achieve this, I would do the following

```
expr = FullSimplify[Integrate[t1^2*E^((1 - h)*s0*t1), {t1, 0, T}]];

rule = h -> 1 - HoldForm[1 - h];

expr /. rule;
```

You can use the resulting expression as is, but if you need to simplify inside the `1-h`, use `ReleaseHold`.